# batch file variable to store file paths

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files with `.arxml` present inside a sub folder. I want to store the file paths in a variable and later this variable is used by a java command.

Folder1 inside this subfolders are present so my .arxml file can be present in any of the subfolders.

In a batch file I want to store in a variable all these `file.arxml` path names separated by a comma and this variable is used by a Java command.

Java command is present in same batch file.

Example

```
@echo start 

Variable = c:/abc/h/f1.arxml , c:/efg/f2.arxml ....etc

Java command -winputs = variable 


@Echo we are back
```

Comment: Perhaps `Set "Variable=c:/abc/h/f1.arxml , c:/efg/f2.arxml"` and `-winputs = %Variable%`

Comment: how to collect file paths in my varibles .... ???

Comment: Give `for` a try.